# webscraping of commercial websites in python

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I'm a chemical engineering student. For a project, I'd like to setup a web scraper in python that could catch certain attributes of the different products. For example, I'd like to go to target and scrape info such as material, weight and a photo. So far I've tried using the lxml library, below is the code that I've tried to use unsuccessfully. I'm not interested in web scraping per se, but the data that I can collect from these websites to perform my calculations. I also found that I'll probably need a web crawler to point the scraper towards the websites I need. Anyways, is it possible for you to point me to a source that can teach this stuff for dummies? I've looked online but so far nothing has really worked.

```
from lxml import html 
import requests 
page = requests.get('https://www.target.com/p/delta-children-skylar-4-in-1-convertible-crib/-/A-52936884#lnk=sametab') 
tree = html.fromstring(page.content) 
data = tree.xpath('//div[@id="product-attributes"]/text()')
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Did you check [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)?

Comment: "...code that I've tried to use unsuccessfully", "...nothing has really worked". What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @mzjn yes, sorry for the vagueness. I am trying to obtain photos, materials, weights and volumes. For example: a coat made of polyester, which weights 5 lb (volumes are not always available). When I go into the script of the website, I right-click on the data I want to save, I select inspect, then I right-click on the html item I want and copy the xpath, yet when I plug it into python it returns a blank. Here's the xpath I tried to copy since my original post: '//*[@id="tab-content-details"]/ul/li[9]/span/b'

Comment: @MikeVelazco I tried using it after you recommended it, but it seems like this library was meant for someone who knows what he's doing. Thanks though!

Comment: Maybe if you take some time checking [the documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html). And if even after trying you don't get it, you can ask a specific question about your problem here and get help.